# selenium in a web service throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception

Tags: java, web-services, selenium, webserver, selenium-webdriver

I created a dynamic web project, implemented a function that uses selenium in it, added the selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar in the project's buidlpath, then used the wizard to generate the web server and the client. It popped up a warning that read:

```
The service class "test.eko3.TestEko3" does not comply to one or more requirements of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification, and may not deploy or function correctly.
The value type "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver" used via the service class "test.eko3.TestEko3" does not have a public default constructor. Chapter 5.4 of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification requires a value type to have a public default constructor, otherwise a JAX-RPC 1.1 compliant Web service engine may be unable to construct an instance of the value type during deserialization.
The field or property "windowHandles" on the value type "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver" used via the service class "test.eko3.TestEko3" has a data type, "java.util.Set", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
```

I clicked ok and it continued generating the server and the client. when it finished and I tried to test it from the client it displayed this exception in the result view:

```
Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver; nested exception is: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver Message: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver; nested exception is: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
```

Then I added the same jar file into the WEB-INF/lib folder and ran it again but it shows the same exception. Is there some other place I need to add the jar? Any help would be appreciated.

The code for the server is below:

```
package test.eko3;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class TestEko3 {
public String Ekobilet(String from, String to, String date) {

    //Firefox browser instantiation
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    //Loading the URL
    driver.get("http://www.amadeusepower.com/trek/portals/trek/default.aspx?Culture=en-US");


    WebElement radioOneway = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_rbFlightType_1"));
    radioOneway.click();

    waitForPageLoaded(driver);


    WebElement fromText = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_txtSearch_txtFrom"));
    fromText.clear();
    fromText.sendKeys(from); 


    WebElement toText = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_txtSearch_txtTo"));
    toText.sendKeys(to); 


    WebElement dateText = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_txtDepartureDate_txtDate"));
    dateText.sendKeys(date); 

    //Sign in button identification and click it
    WebElement searchbutton = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_btnSearch"));
    searchbutton.click();

    String page = driver.getPageSource();


    //Closing the browser
    driver.close();

    return page;

    }

    public static void waitForPageLoaded(WebDriver driver) {

        ExpectedCondition<Boolean> expectation = new
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
           public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
             return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
           }
         };

        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
         try {
                 wait.until(expectation);
         } catch(Throwable error) {
                 System.out.println("exception yavrum");
         }
    } 

}
```

Comment: @JunedAhsan I added the code to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are using selenium standalone jar, which is not good for dynamic web projects in java. See http://me-ol-blog.blogspot.co.il/2013/07/using-selenium-in-java-dynamic-web.html