# Exception using selenium on server side

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a web application which asks user to input a URL. I then, using [Selenium 2.35.0](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/), grabbing the source code from the URL.

I have created a `dynamic web project` with everything setup properly (all selenium jars included), but my application is throwing exception

```
Oct 18, 2013 2:49:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [DiffReportServlet] in context with path          [/PBSkyScraper] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
at com.PB.automation.servlets.DiffReportServlet.doGet(DiffReportServlet.java:38)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

This is what the workflow is :

The user enters the URL and submits. A servlet is called which actually does the job of grabbing the source code. I am unable to understand the reason because the same works if i try it running as a java application and not on server.

Here is the code

```
 /**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String webDir = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/WebContent");
    String url = request.getParameter("url");
    ApplicationUtils.getHTMLSourceFromURL(url, "originalSource.html");

}

public static void getHTMLSourceFromURL(String url, String originalFile) {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get(url);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        List<String> pageSource = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(driver.getPageSource().split("\n")));

        writeTextToFile(pageSource, originalFile);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("quitting webdriver");
    driver.quit();
}
```

Can somebody explain the cause and provide some solution to this? I am using Tomcat as the server.

Comment: anyone up for some leads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally worked out myself after exploring [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17792560/1471314) . I just removed standalone jars and used `selenium-java-2.35.0.jar` moved the lib folder to `WEB-INF` directory and everything worked fine.